# stable splitting into a wedge sum

Tags: homotopy-theory, cohomology, stable-homotopy, homology, loop-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a CW-complex such that there is a stable splitting of $X$ into wedge sum
$$
\Sigma^t X\cong \bigvee _{k=1}^\infty Y_k.
$$

(1). Does this imply 
$$
X\to \Sigma^tX\to \bigvee _{k=1}^\infty Y_k\to Y_k
$$
induce an epimorphism on homology
$$
H_*(X)\to H_*(Y_k)?
$$

(2). Can we construct a map
$$
Y_k\to \bigvee _{k=1}^\infty Y_k\to \Sigma^tX \to X
$$
such that the map induces a monomorphism on homology?

Comment: What's the map from $X$ to its suspension?

Comment: I want the map to be inclusion $X\to X\wedge S^t$. Is it valid?

Comment: @RSQ That map factors through the inclusion of $X$ into the cone on $X$ and is therefore nullhomotopic. Consider the equatorial inclusion of one $S^n \to S^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than thinking about maps $X\to \Sigma^tX$ or $\Sigma^tX\to X$ you should just pre- or post-compose with the suspension isomorphism.

For instance,
$$
H_*(X) \cong \tilde{H}_{*+t}(\Sigma^t X) \cong \tilde{H}_{*+t}\left(\bigvee_{k=1}^\infty Y_k\right) \twoheadrightarrow \tilde{H}_{*+t}(Y_k)
$$
is an epimorphism (the last map is an epimorphism because it's induced by a retraction). So we get an epimorphism $H_*(X)\to H_*(Y_k)$ up to a degree shift.

Similarly you'll get a monomorphism $H_*(Y_k)\to H_*(X)$ up to a degree shift.

Note that the inclusion $X\to \Sigma^t X$ is always null-homotopic.